# How to add an image inside of a <div></div> element when it's clicked with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a board in my html file like the one below and I'm trying to figure out a way to add an image to each empty square when clicked. Each square is 153pxx153px and my image will be 150px150px and I'd like it to show up in the square centered when it's clicked.

```
 <div id="board">
      <table>
          <tr id="row1">
              <td id=1 class="square"></td>
              <td id=2 class="square v"></td>
              <td id=3 class="square"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row2">
              <td id=4 class="square h"></td>
              <td id=5 class="square v h"></td>
              <td id=6 class="square h"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row3">
              <td id=7 class="square"></td>
              <td id=8 class="square v"></td>
              <td id=9 class="square"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
```

For example

[my board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJ3A.png)

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
  td.square {
     width:150px;
     height:150px;
     padding:3px;
     cursor:pointer;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
   var 
   board = document.getElementById("board"),

   imgArray = ['image1','image2','image2','image3',. . .],

   loadImage = function(e) {
     var elem = e.target; 
     if(elem.tagName == 'TD') {
        elem.innerHTML = '<img src="'+imageArray[Number(elem.id)]+'">';
     }
  };

  board.addEventListener('click',loadImage,false);
```

You can add more events to any other cell by selecting them using addEventListener without any issue.

Comment: What to do if we want to add additional action for some .square elements? It will overwrite previous one.

Comment: store all your images in an array. Iterate over all the .square elements and then apply an eventListener with loadImage() function as handler on each of them with choosing appropriate image src from the array, inside a closure.

Comment: What will you do if you need to attach additional events to some of the cells?

Comment: I am adding an edit.

Comment: It's better for use event delegation here.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var board = document.getElementById('board');

board.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.classList.contains('.square')) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = '/image/pic.png'; // path to the image
    target.innerHTML = '';
    target.appendChild(img);
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.square {
  width: 153px;
  height: 153px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this:

```
$("td").click(function(ev){
    // Perform your action on click here
    ev.target.innerHTML='<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">';
});
```

[Click to see a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/q86kgaed/)

UPDATE: If you want to use only JS use the following:

```
var board = document.getElementById('board');
board.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  ev.target.innerHTML='<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">';
});
```

[Click to see a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/q86kgaed/2/)

Comment: pure javascript, no jquery tag, quite sure OP isn't interested in a solution that incorperates jquery only for event binding.

Comment: True @DrunkWolf, I added the JS-only version.